# The proof of $(n+1)!(n+2)!$ divides $(2n+2)!$ for any positive integer $n$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, modular-arithmetic, factorial, prime-factorization, ceiling-and-floor-functions

> Does $(n+1)!(n+2)!$ divide $(2n+2)!$ for any positive integer $n$?

I tried to prove this when I was trying to prove the fact that ${P_n}^4$ divides $P_{2n}$ where $n$ is a positive integer, where $P_{n}$ means the multiplication of all $k!$ from $1$ to $n$, in other words, $P_{n}=1!2!...n!$

So I tried a stronger statement with induction, since if I were to prove the statement

"${P_n}^4$ divides $P_{2n}$ "

using induction, ${(n+1)!}^4$ does not divide $(2n+1)!(2n+2)!$ when $n=2$

So instead I tried proving ${P_n}^4 (n+1)$ divides $P_{2n}$ using induction (first motivated by the want of $n+1$ term in the dividend), but this too seems to be a bit hard since there will be a $n+2$ term in the bottom, but then I tried by plugging a few values from $1$ to $13$ into calculators, it was thus found out that maybe $(n+1)!(n+2)!$ divides $(2n+2)!$.

I tried this by first considering the number of $p$ (prime) dividing the divisor must be smaller or equal to the number of the $p$ dividing the dividend. Namely:

$(\left \lfloor{\frac{n+1}{p}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{n+1}{p^2}}\right \rfloor +...)$+ $(\left \lfloor{\frac{n+2}{p}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{n+2}{p^2}}\right \rfloor +...)$ $\leq$ $\left \lfloor{\frac{2n+2}{p}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{2n+2}{p^2}}\right \rfloor +...$.

Then by letting $j$ be an arbitrary positive integer, it was proven that

$\left \lfloor{\frac{n+1}{p^j}}\right \rfloor + \left \lfloor{\frac{n+2}{p^j}}\right \rfloor \leq \left \lfloor{\frac{2n+2}{p^j}}\right \rfloor$

by considering many cases of whether $p^j$ divides $n+1$.

Is there any other proof more intuitive and more "elegant" than this one where we have to consider the many cases? Or is there even any better approach of proving the original problem? (preferably an attempt of both method, induction and without induction.)

Thanks

Than

Comment: Specifically, the title asks about whether the [Catalan numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) are integers (they are), but the body of the Question seems to pertain to another topic.

Comment: @hardmath Sorry, I was trying to describing the background of the problem posed in the title, is it ok? Or do you have any recommendation of a better title, since it would be not very useful to mention a bit in the title about the origin of the problem.

Comment: I think the title is great, I just wanted to be sure I could provide a solution that answers what you are really looking for.  Background is useful, but I'd include the problem setup ($n$ is a positive integer) and goal in the opening paragraphs.

Comment: @hardmath Thanks! I've added the problem setup, but putting the goal would be difficult since the origin was being described in the opening paragraphs.

Answer (score 6):

Although the expression $\frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+2)!}$ is not quite a binomial coefficient, it can be expressed as the *difference* of two binomial coefficients (and so it is in fact an integer):

$$ \frac{(2n+2)!}{(n+1)!(n+2)!} = \frac{1}{n+2} \binom{2n+2}{n+1} = \binom{2n+2}{n+1} - \binom{2n+2}{n+2} $$

This restates that the [Catalan number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) $C_{n+1}$ is a whole number.